# how to build a local storage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, singleton, local-storage

I'm doing a project and it is based on ajax technologies with rest web-service and I want to maintain a local storage to maintain JSON data retrieved from the rest server and should maintain rest calls and update the local repository when needs.How should I do this approach in raw JavaScript without any frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). But I don't think you should use it for very complicated stuff.